# Android Video Intent Problem

Tags: android, video, android-intent

Last week I published app, this app contained just video links that allows the users to watch clips whenever they click any button link.

I am using this code to play video:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://www.yourvideo.mp4"), "video/mp4"); 
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

However, in some cases this code doesn't work in several devices, some users of my app said it force closes the entire app whenever they press any link. I actually tried it on my Droid X, it worked perfectly fine.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Please help me, I would really appreciate it a lot.

Here is the error I am getting.

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW 
    dat=http://www.yourvideos.mp4 typ=video/mp4 }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
    at com.MyApplication.desc182$1.onClick(desc182.java:34)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and never found a good reason why this happens. I ended up just catching ActivityNotFoundException and showing a dialog.

Here's a way you can tell if there's an activity that can handle a particular intent:

```
private boolean checkCanOpenVideoMP4Url(String videoUrl) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/mp4"); 

    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    return (resolveInfo.size() > 0);
}
```

You can use this approach to see if the intent can be handled, and then message the user appropriately if there is no activity that can handle a particular intent.

Comment: I've got the same problem, but that is not a suitable solution, especially If I have a video player installed that is able to play the video.

Comment: I think the point of catching ActivityNotFoundException is that there is no video player that can handle the intent. Otherwise the OS would just start the activity! One way to avoid catching the exception is to as the OS if there are any activities that can handle the intent first. I've updated my answer to show how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you set action action_View. but there might be case when device is not having any application that has intent filter defined for this action.

Simply device might not be having any media player in which you can preview your video.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by action_View? You mean I have to replace it with something else or remove it instead?

Comment: why to remove it. its absolutely correct. but if you might not be having any video previewer installed on your device. how could you view video.

Comment: I'm in a simolar situation:
1) the .mp4 file is on the sdcard.
2) If I browse to the file with a filemanager, I am able to play the movie with the  video player. (so I've got one and the filemanager lets me choose the appropriate player with the standard dialog)
3) unfortunately this does not works for the app. I never get asked which video player should be used. (my Soution, same as above works on Samsung Galaxy Se but not on the LG Nexus 5)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the response selected is not quite sharp, but the response is almost there.

In my application, the user can see movie trailers, and at our end, we were able to see the trailers, but when application was distributed, we had some complaints saying that trailers do nothing.
Android have a default media player that is not much featured, so the user must have another Media player (like MX Reproductor) in order to see some videos. So, you not only need to catch the exception (as you already do), but also suggest the user to download a proper reproductor.

Another key point were the protocol used to reproduce. Most of the media players can't resolve by using https protocol. So, if you are tring to reproduce using that, you may need to expose in http protocol, or find another workaround.

Finally, default reproductor may prevent to fall into the catch block, given that isn't your application what fails. In that case, the default reproductor will tell the user that the video can't be reproduced.

Here the code you can use:

```
try { 
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent); 
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) { 
    // Tell the user that must download a proper reproductor. Even suggest one that works.
}
```

HTH,
Milton